# How To Create a Parrallax Cover in Bootstrap

Tags: css

I have Problem With To Create a Parralax Cover

```
.divcover {
border: #cccccc solid 1px;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
min-height: 200px;
vertical-align: bottom;
border: none;
border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
margin-top: 20px;
/*margin-bottom: 20px;*/
```

}

```
.divCoverCover {
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);   
border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
```

}

this style contain textshadow but this has a problem with bootstrap
please Help Me !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This Can be Help You

```
.divcover {
    border: #cccccc solid 1px;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-blend-mode: multiply;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #bbb;
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible;
    padding-right: 200px;
    min-height: 200px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    margin-top: 20px;
    /*margin-bottom: 20px;*/
}

.divCoverCover {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
```